# React app doesnt work in safari browser? SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

```
document.querySelector("[rel='icon'").setAttribute('href', {Favicon});

(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').on('click', '.news-text img', function(e) {
            let src = $(this).attr('src');
            const modal = $('#lightBoxModal');
            modal.css('display', 'block');
            modal.find('img').remove();
            modal.find('.modal-content').append('<img src="' + src + '" alt="">');
        });

        $('#lightBoxModal, #lightBoxModal .close-icon').on('click', function() {
            const modal = $('#lightBoxModal');
            modal.find('img').remove();
            modal.css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

SyntaxError (DOM Exception 12): The string did not match the expected pattern.
React app web site and doesnt work in safari!
How i can solve this problem?

Comment: How is this React?  Also, this looks like a typo: `"[rel='icon'"`  And it's not clear to me what this is meant to be: `{Favicon}`

Comment: The error sounds like an issue with your `querySelector` like @David has pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are missing a bracket at the end of your statement:

```
document.querySelector("[rel='icon'") // Original
document.querySelector("[rel='icon']") // <-- Fixed
```

Comment: This is just pointing out to the first comment, 5 minutes later

Comment: @Treycos I opened up a bunch of questions in new tabs and answered them without refreshing / updating comments. I don't see why that deserves a downvote, especially because the answer is correct.

Comment: @BojanIvanac An answer to a question likely to be closed as *simple typographical error*. That's no reason to downvote, but anyway it's not going to help anyone else, except for the OP.